# Renaming numeric keys in nested json using python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to rename keys of json data such that if key has only numbers in it then it should get left padded with a constant string.

```
input_json = {'key1': {'2': 'value2', 'key3': {'key4': 'value4', '5': 'value5'}}}

output_json = {'key1': {'key2': 'value2', 'key3': {'key4': 'value4', 'key5': 'value5'}}}
```

This is what i was trying but did not work:

```
def format_json_keys(d):
    new = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if k.isdecimal():
                d["key" + str(k)] = v
            format_json_keys(v)
        if isinstance(v, list):
            [format_json_keys(row) for row in v]
    return new
print(format_json_keys(input_json))
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to assign the result of the list comprehension to something.

Comment: You're modifying the original dict, not doing anything to `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not putting the updated elements in `new`, you're modifying the original dict. And you should replace the key regardless of the type of the value. The value type just governs how we recurse.

```
def format_json_keys(d):
    new = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        newkey = "key" + str(k) if k.isdecimal() else k
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            new[newkey] = format_json_keys(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            new[newkey] = [format_json_keys(row) for row in v]
        else:
            new[newkey] = v
    return new
```

Answer (score 0):

please  try this?

```
    def solve ( d ) :
        for k,v  in d.items() :
            if k.isdecimal ( ) :
                d["key" + k ] = v 
                d .pop ( k ) 
                
            if type (v ) == dict :
                solve ( v )
                break 
        return d
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you unconditionally call the `items` method of the input object means that the input object has to be a dict, and that the function accepts a list only if it is a value of the given dict at the first level.

You can make the function more generic by using an `if` statement to determine the data type of the input object first before proceeding with the different recursive logics:

```
def format_json_keys(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {'key' + k if k.isdecimal() else k: format_json_keys(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return list(map(format_json_keys, d))
    return d
```

Comment: Thanks. this works and makes the function more generic.